# Probability of collision in linear hashing?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, hash-function

Take an $u × m$ matrix $A$ filled with random bits(0,1). Given a non-zero vector $x$ in $\{0,1\}^u$, what is the probability that $x$ is in null space of $A$. All calculations are done modulo 2. Source of randomness is selection of $A$ from $2^{um}$ choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ is in the nullspace of $A$, then all the coordinates of $Ax$ are equal to $0$, ie for any $i \in \{1, \dots, u\}$: $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^m a_{ik} x_k = 0$.

Now, all $a_{ik}$ and all $x_k$ are uniformly random, so you can deduce the distribution of the product $a_{ik}x_k$. Then, in modulo 2, the sum can be found by computing how many terms of the sum are nonzero.

Comment: Thanks, I was confused with $x$ being fixed non-zero vector but it should be for any uniformly random $x$.

Comment: For completion, $a_{ik}x_{k}$ are distributed as $Ber(\frac{1}{4})$. And probability of their sum being equal to zero is same as the even number of them being nonzero and so $P(\sum_{k=1}^{m} a_{ik} x_k = 0) = \sum_{i\in[0,2,..m]} {m \choose i} {\frac{1}{4}}^i{\frac{3}{4}}^{m-i} = \frac{1}{2}$. So the probability of uniformly random x to be in null space is $\frac{1}{2^m}$

Comment: I fear that the sum you computed is wrong. Take for instance $m=1$, you should have $\sum_{i=0, 2, \dots , m} {m \choose i} {\frac{1}{4}}^i{\frac{3}{4}}^{m-i} = {1 \choose 0} \cdot 1 \cdot \frac{3}{4} = \frac{3}{4}$.

WolframAlpha gives [another answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E(m%2F2)+(m+choose+2k)+(1%2F4)%5E(2k)(3%2F4)%5E(m-2k)): $\sum_{i=0, 2, \dots, m} {m \choose i} {\frac{1}{4}}^i {\frac{3}{4}}^{m-i} = \frac{1}{2} (2^{-m} + 1)$

Comment: you are right. Thanks